# How to add multiple lookup value in sharepoint List.While adding item in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

My Task have multiple relateddocId for example RelatedDoc="3,5,2,6", now i need to add multiplevalue to the sharepoint lookup fields called related Document which is in task list. how to add this?

For ref see my code below

```
   private static void CreateItem(SPWeb web, SPList TaskList, string FolderURL, string ItemName, string RelatedDoc)
    {
        var ParentURL = string.Empty;
        if (!TaskList.ParentWebUrl.Equals("/"))
        {
            ParentURL = TaskList.ParentWebUrl;
        }
        SPListItem _taskList = TaskList.AddItem(ParentURL + FolderURL, SPFileSystemObjectType.File, null);
        _taskList["Title"] = ItemName;
        string DocName = "4,6,3,6";//Document ref id.
        SPFieldLookupValue lookupvalue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

        if (DocName != "")
            lookupvalue = new SPFieldLookupValue(RelatedDoc, DocName);
        _taskList["EYRelatedSharedDocument"] = lookupvalue;
        _taskList.Update();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPFieldLookupValueCollection documents = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();

foreach ( ... )
{
    documents.Add(new SPFieldLookupValue(documentId, documentTitle));
}

_taskList["EYRelatedSharedDocument"] = documents;
_taskList.Update();
```